# BitMap to int[]

Tags: c#, microsoft-tag

I am trying to use Microsoft Tag in Windows forms and have run into a problem with trying to decode an image using the `ScanFromFrame`.

I have an example from Windows Phone that use `TagContext.Current.ScanFromFrame` to find Tags in the camera feed. My problem is that `ScanFromFrame` takes an `ImageToDecode` that requires an `int[]`. In Forms I have a `BitMap`, and do not know how to convert it to the `int[]`.

Have any of you used TagContext with Bitmaps, or do you know how and if I should convert it to an int array?